# Nextjs reformat url's from getstaticpaths

Tags: next.js, slug, supabase

So i'm pulling data from the database using it for dynamic paths, however they look like: http://localhost:3000/Austin/2022-10-21/Dog%20Park [city][date][title].js

How can I prettify this url to format it as:
http://localhost:3000/austin/2022-10-21/dog-park

This would be more ideal for seo reasons.

Comment: Don't use the title as is for the `paths` entries in `getStaticPaths`, use slugified versions of `title` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm leaving towards moving all the relevant date into a [slug].js file and doing it this way